# Is there some way to make alias expansion work inside if...fi on Bash?

Tags: bash, alias

Check this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if true;then
    alias WeirdTest='uptime';shopt -s expand_aliases
    WeirdTest
fi
WeirdTest
```

The first time `WeirdTest` is executed it says "command not found".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a limitation of bash. Quoting the manual:

> The rules concerning the definition and use of aliases are somewhat confusing.

Bash expands aliases when it reads a command. A command, in this sense, consists of complete commands (the whole `if … fi` block is one compound command) and complete lines (so if you wrote `… fi; WeirdTest` rather than put a newline after `fi`, the second occurrence of `WierdTest` wouldn't be expanded either). In your script, when the `if` command is being read, the `WeirdTest` alias doesn't exist yet.

A possible workaround is to define a function:

```
if …; then
  WeirdTest () { uptime; }
  WeirdTest
fi
WeirdTest
```

If you wanted to use an alias so that it could call an external command by the same name, you can do that with a function by adding `command` before it.

```
WeirdTest () { command WeirdTest --extra-option "$@"; }
```

Comment: I have several if..fi defining the (same) alias inside of it (actually thru a sourced huge script); so following your "function tip", I defined a function with the same alias identifier before all the ifs (and so before all source loading) but this way: `function WeirdTest() { eval WeirdTest "$@"; }` so I used eval, and it is now working! I think it did not ended on an endless recursive loop because WeirdTest got redefined into an alias; I believe tho eval should be avoided, but I am still not convinced why, by all I read about, I think I need to research more..

Comment: @AquariusPower I have a hard time imagining a context where this function would make sense, or why you'd want to use `eval`.

Comment: that's the problem, I must fill this gap between your knowledge and mine :), I used `eval` just because it worked.

Comment: anyone interested about "do not use eval" read the last paragraph [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12789461/1422630); and to finally get scared go [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)